# In HTML, how can I create a box with a curved banner scroll on the left hand side?

Tags: design, website-design

I was in a website and it had some boxes with content in them and an image on top of the boxes with some text in them.  Like a title for what the box is for.

The problem is that I don't know how to do this kind of design.

[image]

I am talking about the left side with the curves.

Comment: I would say the easiest was would be to do this with an image. To be precise with a CSS sprite. I think you will also be able to pull this off using CSS3 and JS techniques, but it would be a lot more difficult. If you don't know how to create the sprite and position it using CSS I can help you with a small example.

Comment: i agree with the image option and thats what i was thinking from the start.

Comment: Ok, the image has to be split in two parts, the content, and the fold. Then you create a div with 2 spans inside, one for the content with the text, and one for the fold. Span 1 will have the fold as a background, `display:block` with the dimensions of the fold. Next to that you have the content with your text, with the button part as the background. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: yeah but im talking on how to create the fold i mean can i cut this and change its colors with photoshop or how i could create one of my own...

Comment: Ah that's another question. I would make my own button with the fold. Changing this one is possible, but it would look messy in the end. There are a lot of ready to go photoshop examples online for such graphics, premiumpixels.com is a good example. Finnaly you an do a google search on creating a fold in photoshop. Another example: http://www.wordpressthemeshock.com/folded-buttons/

Comment: thanks Saif Bechan, i really didnt know these designs were called "fold" so i think all are clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's cerated via Photoshop as an image and then simply added to CSS of the web page as background-image of some element (i.e. a `<div>`)

I think the question is more how to build such image in Photoshop?
It might be some new Photoshop effect because I'm starting to see it too often on websites. (It happened the same when PS6+ added the Warp effect, and we started to see on the web many sites with a curl on the up right side of the page.).

[image]

[Here is a Photoshop tutorial](http://psdvibe.com/2008/12/03/content-box-with-orange-banner-heading/) on how to make similar image to the one you asked but with stright angles, I think you need to look for these kind of tutorials.